# Merging rates on a CTMC model

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, poisson-distribution

first time question here. I'm having a rough time trying to represent the following CTMC. Any help would be gladly appreciated.

> We consider a server with a infinite buffer connected to a network. User send files varying sizes to the server. The treatment is done through a FCFS order.
>   However at anytime errors or cancelations may happen, resulting in the deletion from the buffer list of the file currently being processed and/or one or more files in the waiting list. These deletions are initiated by some system tasks. For this case the a system task occuring will delete the file being printed.
>   We make the following assumptions :
>
> - Files arrive to the server according to a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$ (expressed in files/hour)
>
>   - Files have an exponential size with a mean of $m$ pages
>   - The treatment duration of a file is proportional to its size and the server is able to process $p$ pages per minute.
>   - System tasks of type i are generated by the system according to a Poisson process of rate $\alpha$ (expressed in tasks per hour)
>   - The queue has an unlimited size.
>
> 1) Are the assumptions listed above enough for the stochastic process $ n\{t(0)\}_{t\ge0}$ to be a CTMC ? If no give the missing assumptions.
>   2) Draw the CTMC.

I am no makov chains guru, but so far I can't do it mostly because on my model the rate $\alpha$ and $p$ go from the same nodes to the same nodes.

**Idea 1**
1) Supposing $p$ is a Poisson process, therefore the stochastic process can be a CTMC, we can add it to $\alpha$.
[image: Model 1]
**Idea 2**
1) Supposing $p$ is an exponential distribution, we can now model the CTMC. We also add an extra state to differenciate the system task happening (therefore a deletion) and a file being treated normally.

[image: Model 2]

I apologize for the above not being crystal clear, but I couldn't achieve any better. X,D symbolizes the number of remaining tasks in the system after a deletion. It's a tweak I did to avoid merging the rates.